# How to calculate CPU utilization of a process & all its child processes in Linux?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

I want to know the CPU utilization of a process and all the child processes, for a fixed period of time, in Linux.

*To be more specific, here is my use-case:*

There is a process which waits for a request from the user to execute the programs. To execute the programs, this process invokes child processes (maximum limit of 5 at a time) & each of this child process executes 1 of these submitted programs (let's say user submitted 15 programs at once). So, if user submits 15 programs, then 3 batches of 5 child processes each will run. Child processes are killed as soon as they finish their execution of the program.

I want to know about % CPU Utilization for the parent process and all its child process during the execution of those 15 programs.

Is there any simple way to do this using top or another command? (Or any tool i should attach to the parent process.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find this information in `/proc/PID/stat` where PID is your parent process's process ID. Assuming that the parent process waits for its children then the total CPU usage can be calculated from *utime*, *stime*, *cutime* and *cstime*:

> utime %lu
>
> Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in user mode,
>   measured in clock ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK). This includes
>   guest time, guest_time (time spent running a virtual CPU, see below),
>   so that applications that are not aware of the guest time field do not
>   lose that time from their calculations.
>
> stime %lu
>
> Amount of time that this process has been scheduled in kernel mode,
>   measured in clock ticks (divide by sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).
>
> cutime %ld
>
> Amount of time that this process's waited-for children have been
>   scheduled in user mode, measured in clock ticks (divide by
>   sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK). (See also times(2).) This includes guest time,
>   cguest_time (time spent running a virtual CPU, see below).
>
> cstime %ld
>
> Amount of time that this process's waited-for children have been
>   scheduled in kernel mode, measured in clock ticks (divide by
>   sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK).

See [proc(5) manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) for details.

Comment: What does it mean for the parent to be waiting for the child processes?  Will this technique fail if the child processes are forked to run in the background?

Comment: The meaning is that a child's statistics are accumulated into the process which calls wait(2) to reap the child.

Answer (score 3):

And of course you can do it in hardcore-way using good old C

find_cpu.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_CHILDREN 100

/**
 *  System command execution output
 *    @param <char> command - system command to execute
 *    @returb <char> execution output
 */
char *system_output (const char *command)
{
  FILE *pipe;
  static char out[1000];
  pipe = popen (command, "r");
  fgets (out, sizeof(out), pipe);
  pclose (pipe);
  return out;
}

/**
 *  Finding all process's children
 *    @param <Int> - process ID 
 *    @param <Int> - array of childs
 */
void find_children (int pid, int children[])
{
  char empty_command[] = "/bin/ps h -o pid --ppid ";
  char pid_string[5];

  snprintf(pid_string, 5, "%d", pid);

  char *command = (char*) malloc(strlen(empty_command) + strlen(pid_string) + 1);
  sprintf(command, "%s%s", empty_command, pid_string);

  FILE *fp = popen(command, "r");

  int child_pid, i = 1;
  while (fscanf(fp, "%i", &child_pid) != EOF)
  {
    children[i] = child_pid;
    i++;
  }
}

/**
 *  Parsign `ps` command output
 *    @param <char> out - ps command output
 *    @return <int> cpu utilization
 */
float parse_cpu_utilization (const char *out)
{
  float cpu;
  sscanf (out, "%f", &cpu);
  return cpu;
}


int main(void)
{
  unsigned pid = 1;

  // getting array with process children
  int process_children[MAX_CHILDREN] = { 0 };
  process_children[0] = pid; // parent PID as first element
  find_children(pid, process_children);

  // calculating summary processor utilization
  unsigned i;
  float common_cpu_usage = 0.0;
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(process_children)/sizeof(int); ++i) 
  {
    if (process_children[i] > 0) 
    {
      char *command = (char*)malloc(1000);
      sprintf (command, "/bin/ps -p %i -o 'pcpu' --no-headers", process_children[i]);
      common_cpu_usage += parse_cpu_utilization(system_output(command));
    }
  }
  printf("%f\n", common_cpu_usage);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -Wall -pedantic --std=gnu99 find_cpu.c
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Invoking `popen` to call an external utility to do the work is not really the "hardcore" way to use C.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Might not be the exact command. But you can do something like below to get cpu usage of various process and add it.

`#ps -C sendmail,firefox -o pcpu= | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'`

/proc/[pid]/stat Status information about the process. This is used by ps and made into human readable form.

Another way is to use cgroups and use cpuacct.

http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroups/cpuacct.txt

https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Resource_Management_Guide/sec-cpuacct.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's one-liner to compute total CPU for all processes. You can adjust it by passing column filter into top output:

```
top -b -d 5 -n 2 | awk '$1 == "PID" {block_num++; next} block_num == 2 {sum += $9;} END {print sum}'
```

Comment: Why is it important to capture 2 frames? It looks like you're only summing data from the second frame, anyway.

To capture only one frame, you can do this: `top -b -n 1 | awk '$1 == "PID" {block_num++; next} block_num == 1 {sum += $9;} END {print sum}'`. Note that the top flags changed, as well as the `block_num == 1` bit.