# How to write a shell script that can get CPU usage on a linux server

Tags: linux, shell, cpu-usage

I want to know How to write a shell script that can get CPU usage from a linux server.

I do know how to do it with ps and top on a linux pc. While the problem here is I need to submit my job using a shell script to a linux server.

I tried

```
myjob
ps ux U myname
```

It runs in sequence. So, I don't know the CPU usage of myjob.

```
myjob &
ps ux U myname
```

The & sign just suspend myjob. Again, the whole purpose here is to know the CPU usage of myjob.

Please let me know how to run the two line in parallel or there is some other way around.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `&` sign sends the process to the background.

Comment: http://theunixshell.blogspot.com/2012/12/blog-post.html

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. @sarathi I don't know how to let ps get the info when myjob is running.

Comment: @Blender, yes. when using "&" myjob is not running and shows 0.0% CPU usage.

Comment: Does your program ask for input from stdin?

Comment: @Barmar no, my program does not ask input from stdin

Comment: What does "myjob" actually do - not in detail, but does it read files, write to files, calculate pi with a million decimals?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the `time` command:

```
time myjob
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, calling myjob using the "&" at the end simply creates another process with your job. myjob would still run in the background and it would allow you to get the process' CPU usage using top.
For example, I created test.cpp
I ran

```
./test&
```

which returned

```
[1] 7178
```

where 7178 is the process' pid
then

```
top -pid 7178
```

gives the process' CPU consumption in realtime.

Comment: The test.cpp had while(1){int a = 3; a = 2;} looping continually and using 100% of my CPU.

Comment: Also, if you do ps just after myjob was started, it is very plausible that your job did not have time to start it's main CPU usage, so that it may appear as if it used 0%. Try running ps a few seconds after myjob has started.

Comment: Don't call your binaries `test` it is a shell (`bash`) builtin. Call them eg `testprog`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch my bad, I forgot the "./" that I used when testing. I changed my answer

Comment: @Sam Thank you to bring the main CPU usage problem, is sleep the right command for that. By the way  I will vote +1 when I get 15 reputation. :)

Comment: sleep followed by ps would get you one value of CPU usage after myjob started, but myjob's CPU usage could vary over time, would it not be better to use top?
I guess it depends on what you want to do with the CPU usage information

Comment: @YaoZhao also, voting an answer as the right one gives you reputation ;)

Comment: @Sam you are absolutely right. top shows real time interactive CPU usage. My situation is that I cannot see it directly from the machine I'm submitting the job. If there is a systemic way to get the entire CPU usage history of the process would be the best. While the quick and dirty "sleep + ps" is just good enough for me so far.

Comment: @YaoZhao maybe this can help you out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871090/how-to-calculate-cpu-utilization-of-a-process-all-its-child-processes-in-linux?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `iostat` command?

Answer (score 0):

```
myjob &
process_id=$!
...now use the process_id in your ps command
```