# Profiling executable with criterion

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, haskell-criterion

I need to profile a large number of haskell executables, hopefully in parallel. I was able to get the clock time with [`measure`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-1.1.0.0/docs/Criterion-Measurement.html/#v:measure) and [`measTime`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-1.1.0.0/docs/Criterion-Types.html#t:Measured) from the Criterion library, but couldn't get `measCpuTime` or any GC report to work (`measCpuTime` returns a time that's impossibly short). The code looks like:

```
buildProj :: FilePath -> IO ExitCode
buildProj projDir = system $ "cd " ++ projDir ++ "; cabal sandbox init; cabal configure; cabal build"

-- Time a project
instance NFData ExitCode
  where 
    rnf ExitSuccess = ()
    rnf (ExitFailure _) = ()


benchmark :: FilePath -> Int64 -> IO Double
benchmark projDir runs =  do  
  let runProj = "./" ++ projDir ++ "/dist/build/" ++ projDir ++ "/" ++ projDir ++ "> /dev/null"
  exit <- timeout 17000000 $ system runProj -- TODO hardcode timeout
  case exit of
       Just ExitSuccess     -> do {(m, _) <- measure (nfIO $ system runProj) runs; 
                              return $! measTime m}
       Just (ExitFailure _) -> return 100 
       Nothing              -> return 100
```

In short, I'm running the executables with `System.Process.system` as an IO action and I've declared `ExitCode` as `NFData` in order to get [`nfIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion-1.1.0.0/docs/Criterion-Main.html#v:nfIO) to work. What have I done wrong? Are there better tools to do the task?

The file's [here](https://gist.github.com/remysucre/d260af535a6cf683bccd) if you want to play with it.

Comment: Well your child process's CPU time is not your CPU time, so no surprise that `measCpuTime` doesn't do what you want. Not sure how to measure the child process's CPU time, though it is obviously possible since `time` does it.

Comment: I'm thinking to use the GHC API to do the profile, but not sure where to start looking

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871090/how-to-calculate-cpu-utilization-of-a-process-all-its-child-processes-in-linux) SO question and got some ideas. First note that `criterion` uses [cbits](https://github.com/bos/criterion/tree/master/cbits) to enable system-dependent cpu time functions. Let's pretend you're on unix. The simplest thing to do is to directly read from `/proc/PID/stat/cutime` at the start and end of your runs and take the difference. Beyond that, you can actually use the `c` code provided in that question, link it in yourself as a foreign import, and then call that directly from your own code.