# Get cpu usage of entire process group

Tags: python, linux, pid

### The Problem

I have a program I'm running with Popen that spawns a bunch of subprocesses. Those subprocesses close every few minutes to be replaced by new ones. The main process (the program I called Popen on) dies pretty quickly. I'm trying to figure out how to get the cpu usage of everything in the process group.

### What I've Tried

I've tried wait4 and getrusage. I've also tried psutil but I realized that if I want to check the resource usage I'd have to spawn a bunch of threads to concurrently check the resource usage of all the supprocesses and it'd be messy and error prone.

Here's a sample of code that doesn't work. It only gets the resource usage for the immediate child and none of the grand children.

```py
old = time.time()
proc = Popen(["g09", "../sto.com"], text=True, stderr=PIPE, preexec_fn=setsid)
ru = wait4(proc.pid, 0)
new = time.time()
print(100*(ru.ru_utime + ru.ru_stime)/(new - old))
ru = getrusage(RUSAGE_CHILDREN)
print(100*(ru.ru_utime + ru.ru_stime)/(new - old))
```

I need to set a new sid (or pgid) because sometimes I want to kill the process before it's finished and if I don't set a new one then the whole python script goes down with it.

PS

I could just use the time command (like `Popen(["time", "g09",...])`) but I was wondering if there was a way to do this only in python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12871090/how-to-calculate-cpu-utilization-of-a-process-all-its-child-processes-in-linux may give some help.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this doesn't work (I get 0 cpu usage despite fully utilizing 2 cores). I know I implemented it right cause it works with other programs. I don't exactly know why it doesnt work with g09 but I think it has to do with the fact that the parent program dies really quick while the rest of the children work together to find an answer.